# Gradle build-info.xml not found for module app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

> Gradle build-info.xml not found for module app. Please make sure that you are using gradle plugin gradle:2.0.0-alpha or greater

I'm using the gradle plug in gradle:2.0.0-beta2. I randomly get this warning and after this very often either the app is not updated or it crashes.
It is enough to clean and rebuild to fix the issue.

Is there any better way to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same with gradle:2.0.0-beta5.
I can install using adb but not from Android Studio.

Comment: @riper did cleaning help?

Comment: nope! I've noticed however that it installs fine, I just need to launch it manually on device, still annoying though! Since very few seem to have this problem I assume it's not related to the android gradle plugin beta versions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For me it happens on the Mac, but on Windows it works fine all the time. Ever since I updated Android Studio to version 2.0 beta, the issue was still present until official 2.0 Android Studio version.

What helped was **disabling Instant Run in Android Studio** -> Preferences *(search for "instant run" or)* -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run -> turn off

Comment: This did the trick for me.  Not only did I see the error message reported by kingston.  I also saw that Android Studio refused to install the app onto the device when I tried to debug.  Turning off Instant Run per @Balki's instructions did the trick.

Comment: happened to me today on Windows, same solution still work nowadays... even with AS 2.1.2 release and Gradle 2.10 ...

Answer (score 14):

> run->clean and re-run the app. done my job.

Comment: You've probably meant Build -> Clean project

Answer (score 3):

Try removing other gradle versions from studio. 
Let's say you have gradle 2.10 running and also have 2.8 install, the gradle wrapper behaves unexpectedly in this case.
Therefore we have to clean and rebuild every time.

This works in mine case; hope in yours' too. :)

Comment: can you tell also how you make a clean removal of old versions ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `build.Gradle` of project as:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+'

        // using 2.+ will solve the problem
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm to use + isn't a good idea in general. It makes the builds of a given version of the code not repeatable

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same warning/error and learned that in my case it was caused by missing or incorrectly configured .idea files.

More specifically, make sure your "gradleHome" in .idea/gradle.xml is pointing at the right location:

### .idea/gradle.xml

```
<option name="gradleHome" value="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio Canary\gradle\gradle-2.10" />
```

If the problem persists, ensure you app modules is correctly configured:

### .idea/modules.xml

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had to do `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler` and then check `Use in-process build`.