# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' while migrating project from eclipse to studio

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, constructor

I am trying to run my code in studio but continuously getting this error :-

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> Unexpected constructor structure.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried a lot many approaches to solve this error but nothing seems to be working for me

Here is what was doing earlier in my code when this error initially arise :-

**Fragment Call from FragmentActivity**:-

```
  public void showSelectVideoFragment() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (checkCurrentSelectedBtForLeftMenu(lMenuBtUploadVideoWRAP)) {
            return;
        }

        setBtBackgroundForLeftMenu(lMenuBtUploadVideoWRAP);
        addFragment(new SVideoFragment(mLeftMenu));
    }

private void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                PVHomeFragment homeFragment = (PVHomeFragment) fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(FM_TAG_HOME_FRAGMENT);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(homeFragment).commit();

            } else {
                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, FM_TAG_TOP_FRAGMENT)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
```

**SVideoFragment Code** :-

```
public class SVideoFragment extends PVBaseFragment {
private SlidingMenu mLeftMenu = null;
private static final String SLIDEMENU_KEY = "describable_key";

public SVideoFragment() {

}

@SuppressLint({"NewApi","ValidFragment"})
public SVideoFragment(SlidingMenu leftMenu) {
    mLeftMenu = leftMenu;
}


@Override
protected void initFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@SuppressLint({"NewApi","ValidFragment"})
@Override
protected View initFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_video, container,
            false);

    Button btToggleLeftMenu = (Button) v
            .findViewById(R.id.btToggleLeftMenu);
    btToggleLeftMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (mLeftMenu != null) {
                mLeftMenu.toggle();
            }
        }
    });

    ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btSelectVideo))
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showVideoSelector();
                }
            });

    return v;
}
```

I added below lines to build.gradle :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

            android {
                compileSdkVersion 23
                buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

                defaultConfig {
                    applicationId "com.example.app"
                    minSdkVersion 14
                    targetSdkVersion 22
                    multiDexEnabled = true
                }

                 buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
            preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
        }
        allprojects {
            configurations {


                all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile project(':sdk')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile project(':android-3.1')
compile project(':AVIOCtrlDefine')
compile project(':Facebook')
compile project(':SlidingMenu-master')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'the META-INF / DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE'
        exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'the META-INF / license.txt'
        exclude 'the META-INF / NOTICE'
        exclude 'the META-INF / the NOTICE.txt '
        exclude ' the META-INF / NOTICE.txt '
        exclude ' the META-INF / ASL2.0 '
        exclude ' the META-INF / Services / javax.annotation.processing.Processor '
    }
```

After doing all above i was still getting same error so i choose second method that is :-

I called Fragment like this :-

```
public void showSelectVideoFragment() {
    SVideoFragment mSVideoFragment = new SVideoFragment();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (checkCurrentSelectedBtForLeftMenu(lMenuBtUploadVideoWRAP)) {
        return;
    }

    setBtBackgroundForLeftMenu(lMenuBtUploadVideoWRAP);
    addFragment(mSVideoFragment.newInstance(mLeftMenu));
}
```

**And In Fragment** :-

```
 public class SVideoFragment extends PVBaseFragment {
    private SlidingMenu mLeftMenu = null;
    private static final String SLIDEMENU_KEY = "describable_key";

    public SVideoFragment() {

    }


    public static SVideoFragment newInstance(SlidingMenu leftMenu) {
        SVideoFragment fragment = new SVideoFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(SLIDEMENU_KEY, leftMenu);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mLeftMenu = (SlidingMenu) getArguments().getSerializable(SLIDEMENU_KEY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void initFragment() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 @SuppressLint({"NewApi","ValidFragment"})
    @Override
    protected View initFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_video, container,
                false);

        Button btToggleLeftMenu = (Button) v
                .findViewById(R.id.btToggleLeftMenu);
        btToggleLeftMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mLeftMenu != null) {
                    mLeftMenu.toggle();
                }
            }
        });

        ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btSelectVideo))
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        showVideoSelector();
                    }
                });

        return v;
    }
```

But still i am getting same error

** when i run ./gradlew assembleDebug in terminal i got :-**

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero
>   >     exit value 1

Here is my app Dependencies :-

> > +--- project :sdk
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 |         ---
> >     com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 |              ---
> >     com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0
> >     +--- project :android-3.1
> >     +--- project :AVIOCtrlDefine
> >     +--- project :Facebook |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22) -> 23.0.0 (*) |    ---
> >     com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4
> >     +--- project :SlidingMenu-master
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 |    |         ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
> >
> >     (*) |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0 |
> >     |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |
> >
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.4.0 |    |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.4.0 |    |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |    ---
> >     com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0 |    |         ---
> >     com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 |    |              ---
> >     com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0 |    |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0 |    |
> >
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |         --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 |    |
> >     --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
> >     (*) |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.0 |    | 
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0 |    |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0 |    |
> >     --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
> >     (*) |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0 |
> >
> >     |    --- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |
> >     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0 (*) |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.4.0 |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0 |    |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) |    |    +---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0 (*) |    |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0 (*) |    ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0 |         ---
> >     com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*) ---
> >     com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0

**Updated :-**

I have tried every thing like adding up of jars one by one , Also Have created one new project in Android studio then put all the folders inside it , have also filter the google play services dependencies which are required for project , have added plugin for google play services too with gcm.jason file in it.

while running **./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace** command

**i am getting** :-

> Error:trouble processing "java/awt/font/NumericShaper.class":
>   Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or
>   javax.*)

i have done some search related this error and find that it seems to come because of android.jar replication in project but i have not found any duplicate file in my dependencies .

**here is my updated gradle.build file** :-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.petzview.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        dexInProcess = false
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile project(':AVIOCtrlDefine')
    compile project(':Facebook')
    compile project(':SlidingMenu-master')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
android.packagingOptions {
    exclude 'the META-INF / DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE'
    exclude 'the META-INF / LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / license.txt'
    exclude 'the META-INF / NOTICE'
    exclude 'the META-INF / the NOTICE.txt '
    exclude ' the META-INF / NOTICE.txt '
    exclude ' the META-INF / ASL2.0 '
    exclude ' the META-INF / Services / javax.annotation.processing.Processor '
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anybody suggest me a way to solve this problem in android studio.

Comment: Any , suggestion please , i am really stuck?

Comment: Higher up in the gradlew output can you see any error message from the java process that failed?

Comment: Hey , @MarcinKoziński this is what i am getting                Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Observed package id 'build-tools;20.0.0' in inconsistent location '/home/ravi/adt_lollipops/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4W' (Expected '/home/ravi/adt_lollipops/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/20.0.0')

Comment: i just changed the name of android-4.4W to 20.0.0 but now it start giving me error of   *Task 'assembleDebugTest' not found in project ':app'.*

Comment: Sometimes, I have similar Gradle error during build after changing dependencies version. For me, solutuion is in full clean of the project.

Answer (score 3):

I`ve got same problem and I fixed it with [disabling Instant Run in Android Studio -> Preferences (search for "instant run" or) -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run -> turn off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36498021/4948172)
Thanks to @Balki for his answer !

Answer (score 1):

try this: (this looks like it might be the problem)

```
public SVideoFragment() {
    super();
}

@SuppressLint({"NewApi","ValidFragment"})
public SVideoFragment(SlidingMenu leftMenu) {
    this();
    mLeftMenu = leftMenu;
}
```

for more information: [Difference between "this" and"super" keywords in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/difference-between-this-andsuper-keywords-in-java)

Comment: Hello Flummox , Thanks for your reply , i am still getting above mentioned error "Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'."

Comment: I take it that "app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug" is the name of your app? Do you see a fragment or Class name somewhere in the Errors? Looks like you will need to go over all the classes you use to see if the Constructors do what they should... Hope there are not a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey is this project is migrated from eclipse to studio?I got the same error.I solved it by making the project multidex.Rebuild and sync it after that.Hope this will help.Remove the duplicates dependencies.

> [gradle - library duplicates in dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648172/gradle-library-duplicates-in-dependencies)

Comment: Yes , exactly this is the project which migrated from eclipse to studio

Comment: By the way i already added *multiDexEnabled* * true* under *defaultConfig* , Please have look on my gradle mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

My problem was this somewhat unusual constructor

```
public ActionRequest(BridgeActivity bridgeActivity, String url, Response.Listener<RestResult> listener) {
    super(url, Method.POST, RestResult.class, bridgeActivity.new ResponseListener<RestResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(RestResult response) {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }
    });
```

I think the `bidgeActivity.new ResponseListener<RestResult>()` call in that constructor is not allowed, I guess that construction is not implemented by some code generator way down in the dex compiler.